# Microsoft .Net - What SDK packages contain Microsoft.WebApplication.targets?

Tags: c#, .net, jenkins, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a cluster of Windows 2012 R2 build servers (Jenkins, in case it matters) which has been expanded as needed. A recent code update caused a build to fail on the newer machines, with the well-known error:

```
error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found.
```

I have confirmed this directory does not not exist on the node that caused the failure. However, it does exist on our older nodes. I have checked the list of installed programs, even compared between the two servers, but cannot see anything obvious for the origin of this folder. Both machines have the VS2013 build tools installed.
Advice from multiple sources online is to copy the folders off the working node to the newer nodes, but I am struggling to find what part of the .Net SDK contains these folders in the first place. I would rather solve the problem once and for all by adding the SDK package to our standard build node image. Can someone please tell me what I need to install to get these files?

Comment: explore this https://nuget.info/packages/MSBuild.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.targets/14.0.0.3

Comment: Windows Server 2012 is EOL soon - is there a good reason you're still running it?